# Await before returning the observable in Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, promise, async-await, observable, angular-httpclient

I have a service method in angular which is calling the HttpClient get method as follows

```
searchItem(name: string) {
  const headers = await this.getHeaders();
  return this.httpClient.get<Item[]>(environment.itemService + `items/searchByItem/${name}`, {headers: headers});
}
```

I have used this without the headers until now and in the components I subscribe to each of the methods like this.

Now I have to call this `getHeaders()` `async` method for headers and set those before I calling the API.
So the issue is first line returns a `promise` and second line returns a `Observable`. How can I get the headers, call API and returns a Observable as the final result of this `searchItem` like before?

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise

Answer (score 0):

await is only valid in async function. 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules. you need to either use `async` before the function definition.

```
async searchItem(name: string) {
  const headers = await this.getHeaders();
  return this.httpClient.get<Item[]>(environment.itemService + `items/searchByItem/${name}`, {headers: headers});
}
```

or wait for promise to fulfill the ask using `then` method as below.

```
searchItem(name: string) {
   return this.getHeaders().then(headersVal => {
       return this.httpClient.get<Item[]>(environment.itemService + items/searchByItem/${name}`, {headers: headersVal});
  });   
}
```

Comment: I can't use async as first solution, since then I will have to change components as well. So I have to go for a solution like the second one you have mentioned. So now in `searchItem` method, Is it returning a Observable similar to the one without headers?

Comment: you need to use two return methods as defined above. let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: Still is it returning an Observable similar to `httpClient.get` call? Since we are returning inside `then`?

Comment: yes, thats what u were asked in the question right ?

Comment: Yes :) But isn't it returning a promise again? Also the response of the getHeaders should be applied as headers value :)

Comment: sorry my bad while resolving i wasn't reading the header value. can you try now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217262/discussion-between-jaibalaji-and-sandeepa).